# Putting more than one logo in the bottom of a poster

Tags: logos, sciposter

I'm using `sciposter` and I am trying to put three logos on the footer of the poster: One on the left side, one on the center and one on the right side. Can someone help me?

As requested, I am adding a MWE:

```
\documentclass{sciposter}
\title{Title}
\author{My name}
\institute{Institute,\\
    University\\}
\email{email} 
\begin{document}
\conference{Conference}
\maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        This is the abstract.
    \end{abstract}
    \section{Introduction}
    This is the introduction
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add a MWE from your poster to start?

Comment: Done :) Just added an MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You a probably expecting something as the following. (My `it`'s should be replaced by your logos, of course.)

*Remark* The first solution is commented in the code and only the final picture included.

```
\documentclass{sciposter}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\title{Title}
\author{My name}
\institute{Institute,\\
    University\\}
\email{email} 
\begin{document}
%\conference{Conference}
% The first version
%\conference{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{it}\hfill
%\includegraphics[width=5cm]{it}\hfill
%\includegraphics[width=5cm]{it}}
% The version with you logos, renamed VRA, VRB, VRC
\conference{\raisebox{2cm}[0cm]{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{VRA}}\hfill
\raisebox{2cm}[0cm]{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{VRB}}\hfill
\raisebox{2cm}[0cm]{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{VRC}}}
% (The precise values are to be chosen according to your taste. 
% It is a naive solution, hence you should be careful not to overlap logos with too long text of a poster.
\maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        This is the abstract.
    \end{abstract}
    \section{Introduction}
    This is the introduction


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This approach almost worked. The problem now is that the logo's height is bigger than the width, so half of the logo appears off screen.

Comment: @ViniciusRodrigues It means that with your logo(s) it does not fit? If they are not prohibited, please put them somewhere. Then it should be possible to fix the problem.

Comment: http://ccsl.ime.usp.br/files/logoIME+Texto.png
http://www.mecatronica.eesc.usp.br/mecatronica/index.php/pt/downloads/finish/1-logo/20-logo-usp
http://www.imar.unifesp.br/v2/images/fapesp2.png

Comment: @ViniciusRodrigues May I put here a corrected version with these logos?

Comment: It would be very kind of you :)